# Database Save Results, Map.values() and maintaining order

Tags: map, error, database

Maybe because it is Friday afternoon, but I feel like I am missing something obvious here. 
I am trying to work out how I can refer back the errors from a database.insert to the key in my map.

So I have something like this:

```
Map<Id, my_object_c> myDemoMap = new Map<Id, my_object__c> ();
//add values to Map - the Id is NOT directly related to my_object__c

Database.SaveResult[] mysaveresults = Database.insert(myDemoMap.values(), FALSE);

        for (i = 0; i < mysaveresults.size(); i++ ) {
            if (!mysaveresults[i].isSuccess() ) {
        //record that the Id that was the key for this record in the map had an issue, so I can update it at the end of the process
}
}
```

Feels like that isn't that hard, but I can't see how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Second go here. Works by creating two lists with corresponding indexes - unrelatedIds and myDemoList - and then relies on the SaveResult[] array mysaveresults having matching indexes with the myDemoList list:

```
// Build lists with corresponding indices
List<Id> unrelatedIds = new List<Id>();
List<my_object__c> myDemoList = new List<my_object__c>();
for (Id id : myDemoMap.keySet()) {
    unrelatedIds.add(id);
    myDemoList.add(myDemoMap.get(id));
}

// Results order matches myDemoList order; result provided for success and failures
Database.SaveResult[] mysaveresults = Database.insert(myDemoList, FALSE);
for (Integer i = 0; i < mysaveresults.size(); i++ ) {
    if (!mysaveresults[i].isSuccess() ) {
        // Use index to find unrelated id
        Id unrelatedId = unrelatedIds[i];
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I follow - if I want to know the Id in myDemoMap that relates to the my_object__c record that failed on insert, how do I identify it (bearing in mind, I am using FALSE as the database.insert option, so some of the records may have inserted ok)? Just to clarify - the Id in the map is from a different object that has no direct reference to my_object__c (i.e. no lookup etc)

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC Duh sorry I'm more asleep than you are here. I'll delete this answer in a few minutes and try again. In your myDemoMap, can multiple my_object_c correspond to one of the map keys or is the map strictly one to one?

Comment: No worries! One to One as far as I know...let's assume it is for the sake of this discussion...

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC Hopefully this second one is better...

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC 
I have a similar issue, do you have idea where i can find in the documentation what is reported in the Keith C answere... I refer to the comment
**// Results order matches myDemoList order; result provided for success and failures**

looks to me the only way to have a match between Results order and my myDemoList... I'm approaching in this way but I dont like it since I dont have a key that connect the to objects... 

Do you know any official documentation that suggest a similar approach?
thnks

Comment: See docs here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm

Comment: "Each element in the SaveResult array corresponds to the sObject array passed as the sObject[] parameter in the Database method, that is, the first element in the SaveResult array matches the first element passed in the sObject array, the second element corresponds with the second element, and so on. If only one sObject is passed in, the SaveResult array contains a single element."